# Different row on different page with same session data

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL table with 4 rows ( id, name, age, tel ) and I want on the first page to dosplay all NAMEs and once a user click on one of the name to go to different page showing NAME and AGE (using the id row) and a button to third page showing NAME AGE TEL. I know it is using sessions but I don't exactly how to write it

Comment: Unless you try it once yourself, you won't enjoy developing !!!

Comment: I think that's why there are forums where to ask

Comment: Ok shall I give you a brief idea of how to do it?

Comment: you have to fetch all records for first page and display them on first page, then add link on this page to view details on second page, detail link will look like abc.com/detail.php?id=1, in detail.php fetch record having id=1 and display it and so on, hope you get the idea.

Comment: Yes please I can make sessions in php but dont know how to use same ID

Comment: look what @Nathan has answered it will help you.

Comment: You're looking for the whole solution here?

Comment: no Im looking to fix this page1:http://jsfiddle.net/FeaZJ/3/  Page 2 :http://jsfiddle.net/FeaZJ/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [$_GET](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp).
In your first page create a link to the the second page with an url like:

> secondpage.php?id=1

Where `1` is the id of that particular row.
Then In your second page you can get this id from the url using $_GET['id'].
Then retrieve the row with this id value; do a MySQL query to retrieve the values to be shown.
Do the same for the third page.

Comment: so far I have this script page1:http://jsfiddle.net/FeaZJ/3/  Page 2 :http://jsfiddle.net/FeaZJ/4/

Comment: You need to use the value of $_GET['id'] in your mysql query. You don't need SESSION for this.

Answer (score 0):

name1

name2

name3

if you click on name1 than

```
<a herf="showall.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">name1</a>
```

it will to showall.php page and fetch data of id=1 it on another page

this may helpful!

Comment: so far I have this script page1:http://jsfiddle.net/FeaZJ/3/  Page 2 :http://jsfiddle.net/FeaZJ/4/